# Transpose as a linear transformation

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $T:V\to W$ be a linear transformation from the vector space $V$ to $W$. Then this induces a linear transformation $T^t:W^*\to V^*$ from the dual space of $W$ to the dual space of $V$.

Suppose $\dim V= n$ and $\dim W$ = m.

Let $g\in W^*$ be some linear transformation. Then $T^tg(\alpha)=g(T\alpha)$. If $\alpha=\begin{pmatrix}x_1\\x_2\\.\\.\\x_n\end{pmatrix}$ and if $g=\begin{pmatrix}a_1&a_2&\ldots&a_m\end{pmatrix}$. Then we have

> $T^tg(\alpha) = \begin{pmatrix}a_1&a_2&\ldots&a_m\end{pmatrix}T\begin{pmatrix}x_1\\x_2\\.\\.\\x_n\end{pmatrix}$

But since $T^t$ is a linear transformation it must have a matrix corresponding to the standard bases which is the transpose of the matrix of $T$.
Since the $T$ has dimension $m*n$ thus $T^t$ has dinemsion $n*m$.

> But then we cannot multiply the matrix of $T^t$ which has dimension $n*m$ with the matrix of $g$ which has dimension $1*m$. Hence $T^tg$ cannot be defined.

Where am I going wrong here?

Comment: The problem is that when you try to compute $T^tg$, you are thinking of $g$ as a linear map from $V \to \Bbb R$, i.e, as a $1 \times m$ matrix. But in reality, you should be thinking of it as an $m \times 1$ column vector which is to be evaluated by the linear map $T^t$.

Comment: If I understand this correctly it should be like this. Take $g$ which is now a $m*1$ column vector. Compute $T^tg$ as a $n*1$ column vector. Now you have a $1*n$ linear functional $f=T^tg$.

Comment: Yeah, that is correct. The idea is just that when we have a vector space $V$ and a linear map $T: V \to W$ in matrix form, we want to consider only the **column** vector of coordinates of any $v \in V$ when we want to compute $Tv$. Your confusion was probably that when $V$ is a dual space, the elements can also be treated as row vectors since they are linear maps themselves, but that is unrelated to the preceding statement.

Comment: @Shalop I'm searching related post and come to here. Can you help me on [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2420333/are-there-any-motivation-of-dual-space-and-annihilator-purely-in-linear-algebra)? I stuck in what's the motivation of defining $T^tg=gT$. :)