# Are there any motivation of dual space and annihilator PURELY in linear algebra?

Tags: linear-algebra

Are there any motivation of dual space and annihilator PURELY in linear algebra? I can prove some relate theorem about it, but I totally can't get what I am doing. It looks like I am, including the textbook writes were, totally just playing some game on the symbols - define dual space without motivation, define annihilator without reasons, and define $T^t=g\mapsto g\circ T$ without any necessity.

I have seen some people say we need that because it is useful in functional analysis, or category theory. However, I think there should be some persuasive reason that why should we define, and what is the motivation of defining them purely in the linear algebra field. Don't tell me "if you grow older, you will know it." If the reasons for it are all in the advanced courses, then why the authors define it and use it in Linear Algebra?

Definitions in my books:

linear functional: a function from a vector space $V$ to a field $F$

dual space on $V$: all linear functionals from $V$ to $F$

Comment: What dual space? the orthogonal complement? The algebraic dual? What is 'the annihilator'?  Annihilator of something in a module? Interpretation depends on that...

Comment: If the OP is so confused about them, I guess he is just studying finite-dimensional linear algebra.

Comment: Does algebraic dual appear in usual linear algebra textbooks(Friedberg, Axler, etc)? Maybe I overlook it. I only find that dual space $\mathcal{L}(V,F)$

Comment: @Eric Sure, I think that linear algebra books discuss linear functionals. That is the definition of the algebraic dual, would you not agree?

Comment: @rschwieb I haven't heared/learned about the term algebraic dual. Does it come in the abstract algebra course or functional analysis?

Comment: @Eric Both, I would think. You can see the connections of terminology [on the wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dual_space) There needed to be some distinction between the continuous and algebraic dual spaces.

Answer (score 5):

The annihilator is the most natural substitute for the orthogonal complement in a (finite-dimensional) vector space, when you do not have any inner product available.

More precisely, let $V$ a vector space and $S \subset V$ any subset. If $\langle, \, \rangle$ is any non-degenerate inner product on $V$, there is a natural isomorphism $$V \to V^*, \quad v \mapsto \langle v, \, \rangle.$$

It is a straightforward and useful exercise to check that, via this isomorphism, the orthogonal complement $S^{\perp}$ of $S$ is identified with the annihilator of $S$.

Comment: Could you give more detailed answers? I can't see it.

Comment: @Eric Is the orthogonal complement a natural object to you? For a Hilbert space (including $\mathbb{R}^n$ and $\mathbb{C}^n$), you can identify the space with its dual, and under this identification the annihilator of a set is identified with its orthogonal complement. So the annihilator is an obvious generalization...once you've gotten interested in the dual space of a space with no given inner product in the first place. *That* part is a bit harder to justify for me in the finite dimensional setting.

Comment: Your edited answer assumes $(V,\langle \cdot ,\cdot \rangle)$ is Hilbert. For simple intuition that's OK, but if you're going to be relatively precise then you should be completely precise.

Comment: For the sake of simplicity, I am assuming that $V$ is finite dimensional. Of course the generalizations in Hilbert spaces are very interesting.

Comment: Orthogonal complement  is natural to me. :) However, I haven't learned Hilbert space. Can it be explained without mentioning Hilbert's space? :)

Comment: Also, I feel quite non-natural where the definition of $T^t=g\mapsto g\circ T$ come from.

Comment: @Eric $\mathbb{R}^n$ or $\mathbb{C}^n$ with any inner product is already Hilbert, which are the simple examples. As for $T^t(g)= g \circ T$, under the same identification between a Hilbert space and its dual, this is just like the transpose of a matrix. It is how the transformation naturally acts on elements of the dual space.

Comment: @Ian Hmm... still feeling difficult to me.

Comment: @Eric In $\mathbb{R}^n$ you can think of row vectors as linear functionals acting on column vectors through the usual matrix multiplication. A square matrix $A$ acts on a row vector on the right: $x \mapsto x A$. You get exactly the same thing in terms of column vectors by applying the transpose, getting $x \mapsto A^T x$. Thus you are taking "how matrices act on row vectors" and directly replacing "row vector" with "linear functional", which is what this identification that we've been talking about is all about. Keep in mind that this is supposed to be directly generalizing the transpose.

Comment: @Eric A good introduction to this way of thinking about things without actually talking explicitly about linear functionals, dual spaces, etc. is Gilbert Strang's linear algebra book, in Chapter 2.

Comment: I can see that $xA$ is equal to $A^Tx$ despite the size. But don't get what you mean taking "how matrices act on row vectors"(get lost from here). Here $x$ corresponding to the mapping $g$ and $A$ to $T$ right?

Comment: Why do we zigzag the definition of $T^t$ by saying $T^t(g)$ should be $gT$ for any $g:V\to F$? Why does the linear functional involve here? Can't we directly define $T^t$ in terms of $T$? Is linear functional any special? It seems just a function whose codomain is one-dimentional, or just a row matrix, nothing special.

Comment: $T^t$ does not act on $V$. It acts on $V^*$. We can only think of it as acting on $V$ once we identify $V$ with $V^*$. The standard such identification is thinking of a column vector $v$ as the linear functional $x \mapsto v^T x$. The analogy in terms of just vectors is that $x \mapsto xA$ uses row vectors while $x \mapsto Ax$ uses column vectors. Row vectors are like linear functionals, column vectors are like normal vectors. But we identify $x \mapsto xA$ with $A^T$, because this is the matrix that corresponds to the mapping on *column* vectors that has the same properties as $x \mapsto xA$.

Comment: Hi @Ian Recently I finally realize what you mean! I can understand the $\Bbb R^n\to\Bbb R^m$ case especially. On the other hand, I find that $T^t$ can be defined in general vector space, rather than $\Bbb R^n\to\Bbb R^m$. In this case, it is no longer very easy to think via matrix multiplication.  How to deal with this case? Given $T:V\to W$, to motivate the definition of $T^t$ by the previous experience, I first tried to pull back $T$ to $f:\Bbb R^n\to\Bbb R^m$. ..

Comment: ..Then try to argue that $T^t:W^*\to V^*$ can pull back to $g: \Bbb R^m\to\Bbb R^n$ too, and the standard matrix of $g$ is the transpose of $f$. However, it is difficult to achieve this step. I stuck in here.